# About formula of temperature of resistor

Tags: resistors, temperature

I have a 10 W resistor.

[image: https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1VMi4IVXXXXX5apXXq6xXFXXXn/100-Ohm-10-Watt-Wire-Wound-Resistors-Lot-of-10.jpg_640x640.jpg]

I am using this resistor with AC current. I need a mathematical formula for determining the temperature of the resistor over time.

The temperature of the resistor depends on P = V<sup>2</sup>/R and time, such as for R = 20 Ω.

- Formula inputs: V, R, t
- Formula output: temperature.

Is there a formula for this?

Comment: Find  the datasheet of this resistor, it should have the temperature curves.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no formula that can calculate the resistors temperature given only the resistor value, the voltage across the resistor, and time.

You need much more information for this calculation, including the ambient temperature, the thermal mass of the resistor, the rate of heat conduction through the resistor leads, and the rate of heat loss to the ambient air.

Answer (score 2):

With constant voltage, the power converted to *heat* in a resistor is

$$P= U^2 R$$

Problem: \$R\$ is not constant, but for metals increases linearly with temperature \$T\$, i.e. it has a *temperature coefficient* i.e. \$R(T) = R_0 + \alpha \Delta T\$:

$$P= U^2 R(T) = U^2 \left( R_0 + \alpha \Delta T \right) = P(T)$$

So, but what *is* the temperature? The temperature is the amount of heat (i.e. \$\int P \,\mathrm d\tau\$) that can't be deducted into the environment, times some material constant, i.e. something looking roughly like

$$T(t)=\beta\int_?^t P(T) d\tau + \gamma \int_?^t{\left(T_\text{ambient}-T\right)^2 \,\mathrm dt} + \epsilon\text.$$

That means your Temperature is proportional to the integral over a function of the temperature – congratulation, you've found a differential equation with badly defined boundary conditions!

So, no, there's no easy formula; you'll need the supplier of these resistors to tell you the *thermal resistance*. If their datasheet doesn't specify that, you can't go on. Anyway, if someone is trying to sell you high-power resistors without thermal data in a datasheet, stay the hell away from that supplier – there's a high chance you will get something that isn't actually rated for 10W, badly specified, or not as reliable as promised. Simply only buy components from reputable sources ([Mouser](https://mouser.com), [Arrow](https://arrow.com), [Element14](https://element14.com), [Digikey](https://digikey.com)), and not from places like Aliexpress (where your image is from).

Answer (score 1):

There is a common formula, but I doubt it's going to help.

In this case, you should be aware of the concept of [thermal resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_resistance) In general, it is possible to find a number RT such that for power passing through a material or structure, $$ \Delta T = RT x P $$, where delta T is the temperature difference between the two sides of the material/structure, and P is power being dissipated.

Problem is, RT is usually found experimentally.

There are a few exceptions. For instance, if your resistor is in a vacuum, and you know its emissivity, you can find its equilibrium temperature from the blackbody equation. In many cases, though, accurate determination of emissivity is also done experimentally, although common configurations are probably available. Emissivity is a matter of material and texture, and lots of work has been done to determine the effects of these properties.

If you have a resistor which is thermally bonded to a spacer block which in turn is bonded to a large heat sink whose temperature you know, you can look up the thermal resistance of the spacer material and calculate the temperature drop across the spacer from its dimensions. This is commonly done for the packages of power semiconductors, and RT numbers are common on the data sheets of many power transistors and ICs.

Many heat sink manufacturers will provide an effective RT for their heat sinks, and you can use this to calculate how hot a resistor or transistor will get at a given ambient temperature. Note, though, that RT will be different for each heat sink, and will vary wildly with airflow velocities across the heat sink. Even if you're talking "natural convection", which is what happens without a fan blowing, RT will vary depending on orientation of the heat sink. Some orientations will encourage the generation of air movement (which is what actually cools the heat sink) more than others.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume the CORE of the resistor is silicon/clay/ceramic, and assume the CORE is 2mm diameter (1mm radius), and you keep the pulsed!!!! power shorter than the thermal timeconstant of silicon for 1mm cube, then we can reason like this

1 cubic meter of silicon has 11,400 seconds time constant

0.1 cubic meter of silicon is 100X faster, at 114 seconds

0.01 cubic meter (1cubic centimeter) is another 100x faster,
at 1.14 seconds

0.001 cubic meter (1 cubic millimeter) is another 100X faster, 
at 0.014 seconds (11.4 milliSeconds) thermal timeconstant.

Thus for heat pulses faster than 11.4 miliSeconds, the heat has not even completely heated the resistor core, and certainly has not begun to exit the resistor by the leads, or by air flow, or by radiation.

For long pulses, its best to have very short leads out to wide pieces of metal, to heatsink the resistor. Some resistors have double-sided mounting flanges and have flat metal bottoms, to dump the heat into underlying heat sinks, with the heat-path being just 2 or 3 or 4 milliMeters.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple thermodynamics (energy balance) consideration? You have power input (viz. P = V^2/R) to the resistor. This power has to go into heating the resistor mass (viz. mc dT/dt) and dissipation to air (viz. hA(T-T_air)), check out Newton's law of cooling. You get a differential equation for the temperature with some unknowns.

Answer (score 0):

Consider behavior in time. Apply voltage to a resistor and it heats up. As resistor temperature approaches the steady state temperature, at no point is the resistor temperature higher than the steady state temperature.
Since there is no overshoot, a good assumption is that this is a first order process:

$$\frac{T-T_{ambient}}{T_{steadystate}-T_{ambient}}=1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}$$

To determine the time constant, observe that:

$$1-e^{-\frac{1}{\tau}}=0.63$$

Apply a voltage to the resistor, and measure temperature over time. The time constant is the time it takes to get two thirds of the way to steady state.